# When sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats is cleared in Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure

In my solution I need to check when there where some last change done in table/index to determine data freshness.

I'm using **Azure SQL Database** and the best option (and maybe the only one without additional tracking/triggers etc) was to check **last_user_update** in :

```
sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
```

I know that in SQL Server this data is cached and not stored in physical table, so information from there are **lost when SQL Server is restarted**.

But I'm not sure how does it behave for Azure SQL DB, and could not find that info in documentation.

I have noticed that in one of my Azure SQL DB's after few days of data not being updated - that is indexes did not changed (not sure exactly for how many days - trying to look it up at the moment) - **last_update_date was empty**. While I still have rows for some objects, as they where queried and last_user_scan had value, tables that were not used at all are not present at all.

I have some theories to check if for example Scaling DB or health events are clearing up that DMV, but maybe someone have some idea or reference to documentation on that behavior in Azure SQL DB?

For solution to that problem, I'll "materialize" this DMV with procedure and schedule it in ADF, but I would like to understand logic of this "clearing cache" for that DMV in Azure SQL, to know when to expect loosing information from it.

Comment: A peek into MS maintenance periods?

Comment: I did not find anything in health event log, but I just started materialization, and I see that one row disappear just after 2h of that process running (need to check if it was no result of auto-tuning) as that was only for one of index_id for table